# Standard C function is slower at the first call, how to solve this properly?

Tags: c, time

I want to make timing tests for learning how to benchmark using "time.h". But I noticed the first test is always longer.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
time 0.000138
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
time 0.000008
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
time 0.000007
```

If I want to do several tests in the same main() function the results will be unreliable. 
Here is the stupid code who prints the output above.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

const int COUNT = 10;

void test() {
    clock_t start = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
       printf("%d ", i);
    }
    printf("\ntime %lf\n", (double)(clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC );

}

int main() {
    test();
    test();
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

I solved this by ignoring the first "test" function. Also, writing a first "printf" who prints some integer before the tests works too. But I guess it's not a proper solution.

Comment: CPU has cache.  When code and data are not in cache, the code takes longer to run.

Comment: It is not `clock()` that is slower, it is your code that is slower at the first call. This is perfectly expected on modern architectures. And yes, it is the standard practice to ignore the first call.

Comment: @Ploumploum That's a comment. You can expect comments within a few hours of asking your question; that's why you have to be present to respond to requests for clarification.

Comment: There is setup work to be done on the first call to `printf()` that isn't needed thereafter.  That might include memory allocation for the buffer for `stdout`, amongst other details.  It is very common to find that the first iteration takes longer than subsequent ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CPU has cache. When code and data are not in cache, the code takes longer to run.

It's standard practice to discard the result of first run (or first few runs) when measuring performance. It's sometimes called "cache warmup".

Comment: You might mention that most of the time is spent in `printf` that is also called for the first time in the first run. Calling `printf` with the same format once before the first run should reduce the difference as the code for `printf` will have been cached by the CPU already.